# Jenkins Pipeline GitLab API Credentials Management

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, gitlab, authentication, cicd

I have a Jenkins pipeline that executes a build whenever a change is pushed to the appropriate branch. Jenkins uses an API token to authenticate with the GitLab server and checkout the repository. Besides creating a "Jenkins" user account in GitLab and using that user's API token, is there any other way I can manage GitLab authentication for an automated CI/CD pipeline? Each user of Jenkins currently has their own API token.

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing the building using web hooks or just polling? I think it's inevitable that you'll have to create a Jenkins account to manage API access. [This Gitlab link](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jenkins.html) explains how to use the Jenkins Gitlab plugin to manage building when changes are pushed. You'll see they use a Jenkins account as well. This is common practice in my organization to remove single points of failure, such as a departing employee.